# Close Window popup using Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```js
this.switchWindowByTitle = async function (title) {
    await browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        handles.forEach(function (handle) {
            console.log(handle.toString());
            browser.switchTo.window(handle);
            if (browser.getTitle() == title) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm using Protractor to work with Chrome browser and try to close window popup by compare title. I get all window handles and for each of this but my code is just only checked with the first value of list handles.

Can anyone help me to fix it?
Here is my issue detail. It just checks first value and then compares the title

> Failures:
>   1) Compare products Compare product should display correctly
>     Message:
>       Expected 'MOBILE' to equal 'COMPARE PRODUCTS'.
>     Stack:
>       Error: Failed expectation
>           at UserContext. (E:\Protractor workspace\POM_PROTRACTOR\Testcases\TC_04_CompareProducts.spec.js:17:47)
>           at C:\Users\tailet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25

Comment: what if you say await browser.switchTo.window(handle); ? Does that help? My hunch is you are getting the title before the switch completes.

Comment: @JeremyKahan: thank you, but after switch i get title, my problem is this code is not go through all items in handles, it just check first value.

Comment: Yes, but "after" may not mean what you think. The switchTo may not have completed when you do the GetTitle. Another way to test what I'm suggesting is do a .then on the switchTo and put the getTitle inside that function.

Comment: Yes, I tried as you suggested and it doesn't work.

Comment: yes, me too, sorry. If you get rid of the return for now and just log browser.getTitle(), do you see all the titles or just the one?

Comment: I think you need parentheses on browser.switchTo.window(handle); so it should be browser.switchTo().window(handle);

Comment: also since browser.getTitle() returns a promise, pretty sure you need await browser.getTitle(). I just tested that with logging it, and I only got the text if I did await. You will need to make it async function(handle) in the forEach

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, you right. I missing parentheses in my code. Thanks so much again

Comment: Did that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method this will close your pop up

```
closeBrowserPopup: () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    closePopup();
    resolve("done");
  });
};
```